# How to view how much RAM users are utilizing

Tags: ram, ram-allocation

RAM can either be used or unused as seen by

```
cleos -u https://api.eosnewyork.io get account eosnewyorkio
created: 2018-06-10T13:04:19.500
memory: 
     quota:     92.66 KiB    used:     28.04 KiB
```

There is both a quota and used category

When I go to check how many ram_bytes the user (eosnewyorkio) has bought from the RAM market I get a different number

```
cleos -u https://api.eosnewyork.io get table eosio eosnewyorkio userres
{
  "rows": [{
      "owner": "eosnewyorkio",
      "net_weight": "78.5012 EOS",
      "cpu_weight": "168.5000 EOS",
      "ram_bytes": 93482
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

why is `"ram_bytes": 93482` and the `quota: 92.66 KiB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quota = 92.66 KiB = 92.66 x 1024 Bytes = 94,883.84 B
ram_bytes = 93482
diff = quota - ram_bytes = 94,883.84 - 93,482 = 1,401.84

This extra ~1400 bytes seems to be the "gift" after the "EOS AccountGate" incident. :)

See Below:
EOSIO v1.2.1
On Sep-06–2018 at 13:36:41 UTC, EOS New York approved EOSIO contract update v1.2.1 along with 14 other Block Producers.

Part of this update reduced the cost of account creation on EOS by 25% by making a hard-coded change to how each account calculated the total amount of RAM it had available and added 1400 bytes to all new accounts. This reduces the recommended minimum amount of KiB one should purchase for a new account from 4 to 3. **Furthermore, all existing accounts need only to stake, unstake, or buy RAM to free up 1400 bytes of RAM.**